# Convert einsum computation to dot product to be used in Theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I have just recently learned about `np.einsum` and quickly became addicted to it. But it seems that `theano` doesn't have an equivalent function so I need to convert my `numpy` code to theano somehow. How can I write the following computation in theano?

```
IX=np.einsum('ijk,lj->ilk',p1,KX)
```

Comment: Can you provide specific input/output examples, or at least the shapes of the inputs and output?  I think I have it using `numpy.tensordot(p1, KX)` using the `axes` optional argument.

Comment: A while back I translated the `einsum` code to `pure` python.  The code is at https://github.com/hpaulj/numpy-einsum.  There are essentially 2 steps - parse the index string, and create/run an `nditer` iterator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to rearrange your axes to get this to work:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(3, 4, 5)
>>> b = np.random.rand(5, 6)
>>> np.allclose(np.einsum('ikj,jl->ikl', a, b), np.dot(a, b))
```

So with that in mind:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(3, 5, 4)
>>> b = np.random.rand(6, 5)
>>> out_ein = np.einsum('ijk,lj->ilk', a, b)
>>> out_dot = np.transpose(np.dot(np.transpose(a, (0, 2, 1)),
...                               np.transpose(b, (1, 0))),
...                        (0, 2, 1))
>>> np.allclose(out_ein, out_dot)
```