# numpy 3D dot product

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, dot-product, array-broadcasting

I have two 3dim numpy matrices and I want to do a dot product according to one axis without using a loop:

```
a=[ [[ 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0]],
    [[ 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0]],
 [ [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0]],
 [ [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0]],
 [[ 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0]],
 [[ 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0.]],
 [[ 0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0]]]

b=[[[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0.],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0.]],
 [[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0.],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0.]],
 [[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0.],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0.]],
 [[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0.],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0.]],
 [[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0.],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0.]],
 [[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0.],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0.]],
 [[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0.],
  [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0.],
  [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0.]]]
dt = np.dtype(np.float32)
a=np.asarray(a,dtype=dt)
b=np.asarray(b,dtype=dt)
print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)
```

a has the shape of (7, 4, 15) and b has the shape of (7, 4, 5).
I want the c=np.dot(a,b) be in the size of (7,5,15) as below:

```
c = np.zeros((7,15,5))
for i in range(7):
   c[i,:,:] = np.dot(a[i,:,:].T , b[i,:,:])
```

But I am looking for a solution without a for-loop. something like:

```
c = np.tensordot(a.reshape(4,7,5),b.reshape(7,4,15),axes=([1,0],[0,1]))
```

but this one doesn't work as expected.

I also tried this:

```
newaxes_a=[2,0,1]
newaxes_b=[1,0,2]

newshape_a=(-1,28)
newshape_b=(28,-1)
a_t = a.transpose(newaxes_a).reshape(newshape_a)
b_t = b.transpose(newaxes_b).reshape(newshape_b)
c = np.dot(a_t, b_t)
```

which didn't work as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with the for loop? If you are running numpy with an optimized BLAS it is the fast version posted so far.

Comment: @Ophion Actually, I am looking for a Theano-based solution at the end. I replied your comment in my other related question I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
#to match the given example
c2 = np.einsum('ijk,ijl->ikl',a,b)
print np.allclose(c, c2)
```

Another one using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
c = (a[:,:,None,:]*b[...,None]).sum(1)
```

Comment: oh ... great! :) Is there an equivalent function in theano as well? I also need to implement it in theano.

Comment: @Anxam How about broadcasting on theano? Check out the solution based on that.

Comment: a solution is provided here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305891/convert-einsum-computation-to-dot-product-to-be-used-in-theano
But i am not sure if it will work for me or not.

Comment: @Anxam Conditions are slightly different as here you are "cutting" one dim and "keeping" one dim. In the linked question, it deals with just "cutting" one  dim. So, if you were to replicate that same behavior here, you would need reshaping and transposing. That would be a messy solution.

Comment: I see...what if I generate a matrix using indexes calculated similar to einsum and build a bigger matrix using these indices to feed into my theano function? i am not quite sure how it will work, but maybe it's better to work on the two matrices that by applying a theano.dot results in what I want.

Comment: @Anxam Just curious and off-topic from your question - Did that broadcasting based solution work on theano?

Comment: I couldn't find a theano-based solution yet. when I succeed, I will post the solution in here, or in my other post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005271/theano-version-of-a-numpy-einsum-for-two-3dim-matrices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96596/discussion-between-anxam-and-divakar).

Comment: @Ophion found a solution:
`tc = T.batched_tensordot(ta, tb, axes=[[1],[1]]) f_c= theano.function(inputs=[ta,tb], outputs=tc) print(np.shape( f_c(a,b)))`

Comment: do you know a similar solution for np.divide instead of dot product? something that work in a similar way to divide instead of multiply?