# numpy.einsum 'ij,kl->ik' how to do this by numpy.tensordot

Tags: python, theano, numpy-einsum

I have two matrix , 5x4 and 3x2.
I want to get a 5x3 matrix from them.

```
>>>theta_ic = np.random.randint(5,size=(5,4))
>>>psi_tr  = np.random.randint(5,size=(3,2))
```

I can do this by

```
>>>np.einsum('ij,kl->ik',theta_ic,psi_tr).shape
(5,3)
```

But I don't know how to do this by numpy.tensordot
I tried this

```
>>>np.tensordot(theta_ic,psi_tr,((1),(1)))
```

I get an error

```
ValueError: shape-mismatch for sum
```

The math behind is

```
z_ij = \sum_{c=1}^4{x_{ic}}\sum_{d=1}^{2}{y_{jd}}
where i=[1,...,5], j=[1...3]
```

Why I need to migrate `einsum` to `tensordot`?

Because i'm doing my research using `pymc3` package
which use `theano` as backend to accelerate computation.

However, `theano.tensor` doesn't support `einsum`, and it only support `tensordot`, the same grammar as `np.tensordot`.

Comment: Why do you need it through `tensordot`? What's wrong with `einsum`?

Comment: What's the problem with https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum?

Comment: I want to do this by theano.tensor.tensordot, and theano.tensor does not support einsum.

Comment: it is not a duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305891/convert-einsum-computation-to-dot-product-to-be-used-in-theano)

Comment: The shape of the two tensors is very different.

Comment: True. Removed the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your einsum formula

```
'ij,kl->ik'
```

uses the indices `j` and `l` once means you can sum over them before the operation.

```
theta_ic2 = np.sum(theta_ic, axis=1)
psi_tr2 = np.sum(psi_tr, axis=1)
```

and you end up with

```
'i,k->ik'
```

which is simply the outer product

```
theta_ic2[:, None] * psi_tr2
```

or in one line

```
np.sum(theta_ic, axis=1)[:, None] * np.sum(psi_tr, axis=1)
```

And in `np.tensordot`, setting `axes=0` will produce the outer product:

```
np.tensordot(np.sum(theta_ic, axis=1), np.sum(psi_tr, axis=1), axes=0)
```